# PowerShell get permissions on a folder for a user with group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directory, powershell-2.0, acl

I have to print the permissions of a user for a specific folder. Below, I have a working code. However it only scans if the user has been specifically given permissions. Now I also want to check, if a group of which the user is a member of, has permissions on the folder.

I thought about listing all groups in which my user is a MemberOf and then add them into a Generic List. Afterwards, I will execute the following code for each entry of this list.

```cs
$User = "testumgebung\cbruehwiler"
$Path = "T:\"
# Generic list object to store output in
$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

# Fields we want in list, an array of calculated properties.
$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
#    @{name="User" ;       expression={$User}}
) 
# Store all objects in variable
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

# Iterate through every object
foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    # Iterate through every individual user right within each object
    # Add it to our list if it matchers our $User
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) {
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
    }   
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.txt
```

My list prints the folder name, the different permissions and if it has access or not. I don't really want to change the structure too much.

Comment: I wonder how you're planning to work with AD if modules are prohibited? Through .NET assemblies?

Comment: You don't necessarily need AD modules for simply reading out the groups of a user. If i'm not wrong

Comment: Only for local groups. AD groups will require the module.

Comment: @montonero No. You can use .Net objects for working with AD without the AD module. It's a pain in the rear, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't say you can't. My very first comment was about it.

Comment: @montonero I saw your first comment. Yet your second comment literally said that for AD groups the [AD] module were required. Which is incorrect.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers My second comment answered the OPs assumption about checking local vs AD groups. I believe the discussion should considered as a whole, not ripped off single words and lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$User = "Testumgebung\cbruehwiler"
$UserOhneDomain = "cbruehwiler"
$Path = "T:\"
$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserOhneDomain 

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null
} 

# Fields we want in list, an array of calculated properties.
$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
#    @{name="User" ;       expression={$User}}
) 
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User)
        {
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
    }   
}


foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList){
            if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("TESTUMGEBUNG\" + $GroupArrayItem)) 
            {
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }   
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.txt
```

This Script checks all rights from a user on a file or share including all of the groups the user is a member of.

You just have to enter the user once with the "DOMAIN\username" variant and once with the "username" variant.

Hope this helps